# How to stop While Loops in python? (i've tried using break)

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, break

This is my first post ever about programming!
Folks, when i execute this algorithm (a guessing game), it doesnt stop asking me for more inputs, even when i write "quit", that was supposed to be the quiting word. The "break" order doesnt work, and i can't find out why. Maybe it works, but when it quits the loop, it executes the "startgame()" at the bottom, but i need this "startgame()" at the bottom to make the game run for the first time, since the game is inside a function and i need to call it to start the game.

```
import random

def startgame():
    a = random.randint (1,10)
    cont = 0

    while True:
        b = input("Guess a number: ")
        if b == 'quit':
            break
        elif int(b) > a:
            print("Too high!")
            cont += 1
            True
        elif int(b) < a:
            print ("Too low!")
            cont += 1
            True
        elif int(b) == a:
            print ("You got it right!")
            print ('You needed ',cont,'guesses!')
            startgame()

startgame()
```

Any ideas about how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a few small issues, but it actually works, you just didn't test enough to find your actual problem.

The issues:

- the `True` lines don't do anything, you don't need them for the `while` loop; the `while` will evaluate the `True` right after it and loop forever.
- you're mixing single and double quotes for your strings - that gets hard to read and confusing quickly, so you're better off using one style, preferably whatever PEP8 recommends. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

The problem:

- your `break` works just fine; try running your script and entering 'quit' at the first prompt, it quits as expected.
- the reason it appears not to work is because you restart the entire game by calling the `startgame` function again after winning the game. This causes a new, nested call from within the game (think 'Inception') and when the game breaks, it ends up on the previous level.

A solution would be to remove the call to `startgame()` and instead wrapping the whole thing in a second while, for example like this:

```
import random


def startgame():
    b = 0
    while b != 'quit':
        a = random.randint(1, 10)
        cont = 0

        while True:
            b = input('Guess a number: ')
            if b == 'quit':
                break
            elif int(b) > a:
                print('Too high!')
                cont += 1
            elif int(b) < a:
                print('Too low!')
                cont += 1
            elif int(b) == a:
                print('You got it right!')
                print('You needed ', cont, 'guesses!')


startgame()
```

Comment: This code fails in Python 2. I believe it is the same problem as the original poster. The result is `TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Quitter'`.

Comment: I agree the `startgame` call needs to be removed.

Comment: When i execute this code, i keep geting the same random number. Something is not right!

Comment: @AlexTaylor that problem does not apply to this script. The script works on Python 2 as expected. The message seems to suggest you're running code from the quitter module from  "Programming Python, 3rd Edition."

@AlexTaylor the startgame() call is not the problem; but you can remove it, if you remove the code from the function.

@RafaelSouza the default for `PYTHONHASHSEED` is to be disabled in Python 2. This causes the random function to always start with the same value. May vary depending on the distribution. Provide a seed yourself (e.g. timestamp) to get a new sequence every time.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the startgame() from inside the loop and replace it by break

```
import random

def startgame():

    a = random.randint (1,10)
    cont = 0

    while True:
        b = input("Guess a number: ")
        if b == 'quit':
            break
        elif int(b) > a:
            print("Too high!")
            cont += 1

        elif int(b) < a:
            print ("Too low!")
            cont += 1

       elif int(b) == a:
            print ("You got it right!")
            print ('You needed ',cont,'guesses!')
            break # remove this break statement if you want to restart it again after winning  

startgame ()
```

Comment: This helps somewhat, but changes the flow of the game, where it no longer restarts after winning.

Comment: if he wants to restart it after winning, means he can remove the break statement

Answer (score 0):

For times like these, I usually use a simple control variable and run the loop on it. For ex:

```
right_guess=False
while not right_guess:
```

and then just go

```
if guess=right:
    right_guess=True
    break
```